# Can I retrieve filters from a column in a database for Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, filter

I want to add a table to my database that holds group filters so crystal reports can retrieve its filter criteria from which ever row it is currently on.  I want to do this so I can have some form of filter template.

I have been successful with this if only ONE filter such as:

```
{Devices.Test} like "1";
```

But if I have multiple:

```
{Devices.Test} like ["1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "5", "6"];
```

It ignores the filter, I guess because the filter is being passed to Crystal Reports as a string instead of Crystal Reports recognizing that its an array.

Has anyone ever done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
MakeArray(Split({databaseColumn}, DelimeterType))
```

And pass that off to your filter criteria. That will split your string up into an array that crystal reports can recognize.